# MySQL fixed allowed combinations from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, database-design, combinations

I am designing a database to organize materials for 3D production.

Materials are named like 1_Fabric_01_Textile_001_BlueJeans_Denim and 2_Metal_02_BrushedMetal_002_ChromeBrushed_Chrome, etc

So, I need a materials table, which basically has information on material name (last value, look above) and a combination of type and subvariant. Each type has allowed variants like 1_Fabric has 01_Textile, 02_Leather, 2_Metal has 01_Metal, 02_BrushedMetal and so on.

Now making all combinations would not be difficult (i.e., being able to choose every possible subvariant for every material type), but I want to limit the combinations to only allowed combinations, so users cannot choose invalid combinations (like 1_Fabric_01Metal or 2_Metal_01Textile).

Any ideas?

Comment: looks like qa simple problem os creating a relational table example: [Type], [SubType], [Type_SubType]. You can even create a [SubType_Subtype] relational table to get more levels of variations

Comment: Yes, but how do I do it? Materials table basically needs a foreign key that show to correct combination of type_ID and subType_ID,

Comment: You give a PK to [Type] another to [SubType] and a relational table just stores those combination as FKs [Type_SubType] (FK_Type, FK_SubType). At you select you join those 3 tables and no, nor Type or SubType ill get FKs directly for one another

Comment: I still need information from type and subtype tables. I will do a simple GUI plugin that will allow user to save the material. Concept is to use drop down box to choose type first, then available (correct) subtype and finally enter the name of the material. The information is then stored in DB in table materials and can be then used further.

Answer (score 0):

In order to generate those kind of name

```
1_Fabric_01_Textile
2_Metal_02_BrushedMetal
```

Based on the followin tables

```
    Type
    ----------
    Id  Name
    --  ------
     1  1_Fabric
     2  2_Metal


    SubType
    ------------
    Id  Name
    --  ------
     1  01_Textile
     2  02_Leather
     3  01_Metal
     4  02_BrushedMetal
```

And keeping rules on what types can relate to subtypes
You ill need a relational table like:

```
    Type_SubType
    -----------------
    TypeId  SubTypeId
    ------  ---------
         1          1
         1          2
         2          3
         2          4
```

and if you need more levels of subtypes you can add more tables

```
1_Fabric_01_Textile_001_BlueJeans_Denim
2_Metal_02_BrushedMetal_002_ChromeBrushed_Chrome

SubSubType
--------------
Id  Name
--  ----------
 1  001_BlueJeans_Denim
 2  002_ChromeBrushed_Chrome

Type_SubType_SubSubType
-------------------------
TypeId  SubTypeId  SubSubType
------  ---------  ----------
     1          1           1
     2          3           2
```

Now the trick part is to do a better normalization for the third level relation. It can be achieved if you add a identity column to the first relational table
So instead you can use this example:

```
Type_SubType
---------------------
Id  TypeId  SubTypeId
--  ------  ---------
 1      1          1
 2      1          2
 3      2          3
 4      2          4
```

and relating it to the second relational table

```
Type_SubType_SubSubType
-------------------------
Type_SubTypeId  SubSubType
--------------  ----------
             1           1
             3           2
```

to retrieve only the possible matches is trivial

```
select * from type tp
join Type_SubType tp_sb on tp_sb.TypeId = tp.Id
join SubType sb on sb.Id = yb_sb.SubTypeId
```

or just (if you already selected a type and put it in the variable @TypeId)

```
Select * from SubType sb
join Type_SubType tp_sb on tp_sb.SubTypeId = sb.Id
where tp_sb.TypeId = @TypeId
```

and so on for SubSubTypes

**note:** this solutions only covers a fixed (or maxed) number of sub-sub. To get a total dynamic level of abstractions you ill need a recursive FK. Not something like rocket science but if you still the basics on SQL try stick with the most simple example.

Comment: Thank you jean. I was ahead of myself and tried to do things without getting the basic concepts. Back to the books for me, will reffer back. Thank you again.